# How do I import com.android.support.test.espresso.contrib ? I have added the required dependencies and yet it says Cannot resolve symbol contrib?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-espresso

I have added the following dependencies for espresso testing in my app's build.gradle file :

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
testCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'


androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0'


androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2"){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Yet, when I try

```
import android.support.test.espresso.contrib
```

It tells Cannot resolve symbol 'contrib'. What should I do?

Comment: Do you solve this question?!

Answer (score 1):

The code for your espresso tests have to be within the `src/androidTest/java` source tree (reference: the android developer training resources, [ui-testing](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/)).

For me the espresso classes could only be found after moving the tests into this special source folder.

---

In java you cannot import a package. You can either import all classes from a package:

```
import android.support.test.espresso.contrib.AccessibilityChecks;
```

or you can import all classes from a package:

```
import android.support.test.espresso.contrib.*;
```

Also, very important: your tests using espresso have to be

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that. My problem is contrib is not recognized even though I have added the dependencies so it doesn't make sense to type contrib.* or any class as contrib itself is not recognized. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @SurajSuresh I've found time to explore the issue and updated my answer

Comment: @ ThomasKläger Thank you Sir. The test cases were in src/androidTest/java and all the dependencies were included in build.gradle file and still it wouldn't work. After a lot of research, when no technical solution was found, I tried one non-technical method which was suggested in a website. I entered the name of the package and class even though android wasn't recognizing it and was giving me the error "Cannot resolve symbol". Then closed Android Studio and reopened it and BAM! the classes were recognized. I have no explanation how.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem according to this [link](https://gist.github.com/rafaelwkerr/9f13f4810d2e713f6476)

I add this dependency to build.gradle.

```
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
```